# problem with bibliography concerning online refferrences

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, urls, greek

I have the following code in Latex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,two side]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=160mm,top=5mm,bottom=60mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tipa}


\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\addbibresource{reffence.bib}
```

I have also a `refference.bib` file to write my references. Everything with `@article` and `@book`  citations work fine. The problem is with `@online`  types of references and especially with url.....
For example when I write:

```
@online{simplex2,
    author        = {\textlatin{Pandano}},
    title         = {\textlatin{Knuth: Computers and Typesetting}},
    year          = {1984},
    url           = {\textlatin{http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html}}
}
```

I get as url ugly things in Greek.

[image]

How can I fix it, please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to compile your document is an option for you, the formatting issue you've encountered can be fixed easily by employing the `fontspec` package along with a suitable font family, i.e., one that features the required Greek glyphs. No need for `\textlatin` wrappers.

[image]

*Aside*: When switching from using pdfLaTeX to using either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile your document, be sure to not load the `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages any longer. Instead, you should load either the `fontspec` or the `unicode-math` package. The latter will be useful if you need to specify a non-default math font. (The default math font is (still) Computer Modern Math Italics.)

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{reference.bib}
@online{simplex2,
    author        = {Pandano},
    title         = {Knuth: Computers and Typesetting},
    year          = {1984},
    url           = {http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ebgaramond} % or some other suitable font 

\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks,  Actually I write in overleaf,  I hope this also works for me.

Comment: @dmtri - You're welcome. Overleaf lets you switch to XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX quite easily: Click on the "Menu" button in the upper left corner; about halfway down the column, you'll see choices for "Compiler". Open the drop-down list and select either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. While you're at it, you can (should?) also change the version of the TeXLive distribution you work with to the latest year (currently 2021).